# VisualStudio 2019 is it possible te set the build variables from CMAKE. And more generally how to set them up

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, build

I am keeping asking questions about VisualStudio but to be honest I do not understand a word from its documentation.

In the json files generated by the VS are placed build variables like  `${workspaceRootFolderName}`, `${workspaceRoot}`, `${env.gccpath}` etc etc but I do not know how to set it up.

If the the CMAKE project.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to set those variables from CMAKE files?
2. If not how can I set them up another way. At the moment project builds but VS generated launch files cannot evaluate the variables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are target properties that can be used to set these kind of variables in a Visual Studio project.  They all begin with `VS_`. I didn't see any that corresponded with these particular variables in this project.

The alternative seems to be to save them in a User props file and you can set property that incorporates that file into your project.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_USER_PROPS.html